# align images in "li" tags

Tags: html, css

I have thumbnails of images on my site. This is how it looks:
[image]

Let's consider the second row. There are two images( always two images in row) and I want to make that the second picture was aligned to the right.
How can I do this?

This is example what I want:
[image]

This is the html code:

```
<div class="navigation_container">
            <div id="dpthumbs0" class="navigation">
                <a href="#" class="pageLink prev"></a>
                <ul style="opacity: 1;" class="thumbs">
                        <li class="selected" style="opacity: 1;"><a rel="history" title="image" class="thumb" href="#1">
                            <img height="60px" style="height: 58px; max-width: 79px;" src="/Image/GetImage?imageName=571437e8-ecfc-46f4-a14f-a645428fae46-pic_172.jpg">
                        </a></li>   
                        <li class="" style="opacity: 1;"><a rel="history" title="image" class="thumb" href="#2">
                            <img height="60px" style="height: 58px; max-width: 79px;" src="/Image/GetImage?imageName=5ef5e802-916a-4ede-af11-c90274c63218-pic_176.jpg">
                        </a></li>   
                        <li class="" style="opacity: 1;"><a rel="history" title="image" class="thumb" href="#3">
                            <img height="60px" style="height: 58px; max-width: 79px;" src="/Image/GetImage?imageName=fa6f5671-b9f6-48e6-a822-cea83424643c-pic_178.jpg">
                        </a></li>   
                        <li class="" style="opacity: 1;"><a rel="history" title="image" class="thumb" href="#4">
                            <img height="60px" style="height: 58px; max-width: 79px;" src="/Image/GetImage?imageName=10b628ed-387e-43b5-908b-80b92efb7d2b-pic_180.jpg">
                        </a></li>   
                </ul>
                <!-- .thumbs-->
                <a href="#" class="pageLink next"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- .navigation-->
        </div>
```

This is all css:

```
.navigation_container {
    float: right;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 30px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.navigation {
    height: 275px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 175px;
}
.slider .thumbs {
    width: 175px;
}
.thumbs li {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 8px;
}
.thumbs li img {
    border: 1px solid #424D55;
    height: 58px;
    max-width: 79px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since `column` is a logical structure in your case, you can try introducing `<div class="column"></div>` type of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create **two classes** & define like that:

**CSS**

```
.left{
 float:left;
 clear:left;
}
.right{
 float:right;
 clear:right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="left"></li>
<li class="right"></li>
<li class="left"></li>
<li class="right"></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS code

```
.thumbs li.alt {
    float: right;
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 0px;
}
```

Add class .alt to every 2nd li, use your template engine's for loop or something similar :). This way in the future if you decide to turn off the right alignment, you just have to modify 1 css class.

```
<li class="">...</li>   
<li class="alt">...</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

neither of these css rules change the html embedded picture alignment to fall to right side inside

```
<ul>
```

tags...